# XML unmarshal does not respect the root element namespace prefix definition

Tags: go, xml-parsing

Here is the XML structure:

```
<root xmlns:test="http://test.com/testns">
            <test:sub>
                <title>this is title</title>
            </test:sub>
</root>
```

It gets unmarshalled with the structs defined below:

```
type Root struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"root"`
    Sub *Sub
}

type Sub struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name `xml:"http://test.com/testns sub"`
    Title         string   `xml:"title"` 
}
```

This is what gets marshalled back:

```
<root>
    <sub xmlns="http://test.com/testns">
        <title>this is title</title>
    </sub>
</root>
```

The root namespace prefix definition gets removed after the marshal and the sub element is using url namespace instead of the prefix. Here is the [code](http://play.golang.org/p/13NT6YcYOd)

Is there any way that marshal/unmarshal won't change the xml structure? thanks!

Comment: It's look like xml namespaces does not work properly for now https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9519 https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11841

Comment: If so then that's an answer and is probably best made into an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it changed the logical structure.  In your original input, the `root` element declares a prefix `test` for the namespace `http://test.com/testns` but it doesn't actually declare itself to be in that namespace.

Here's an alternate version that does what it looks like you want: https://play.golang.org/p/NqNyIyMB4IP

I bumped the namespace up to the `Root` struct and added the `test:` prefix to the `root` xml element in the input.

Comment: Though I'm not sure it's handling the `title` element correctly.  When the namespace is declared with `xmlns:test` and the `title` element name doesn't have a prefix, I don't believe it's supposed to be in the namespace.  However, in the processed version, with the raw `xmlns` declaration, all children are automatically in the namespace...  As @RoninDev mentioned, the stdlib xml libraries are not so great with namespaces.